# Need help modifying this to load internal hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

Okay, so I have this script that loads external files but now I want to modify it so that it loads internally hidden content. Can someone please help me with this. There's two part to this script: 1) when someone clicks on a certain link with the class "o-links" it slides open displaying the requested content. Then there's the other link (o-close-link) that closes the previously slide open display area.

Also I've been trying to add a gif loader but with no luck. I just really want this to work, but I've tried to no avail. Please help me fix this someone, anyone. Please!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.o-links').click(function() {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            $.get(href, function(data){
                $('.reserved-area').hide('fast');
                $('.reserved-area').html(data).slideDown('slow');
            });

            return false;
        });


        $('.o-close-link').click(function() {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            $.get(href, function(data){
                $('.reserved-area').hide('fast');
                $('.reserved-area').html(data).slideDown('slow');
            });

            return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: try use these examples http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ .done(), .fail(), .always() functions.

Comment: is it a typo you have typed $('reserved-area') ? it must be $('.reserved-area')

Comment: yeah it is a typo. sorry.

Comment: try `$('.reserved-area').html(data).hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this solution you shoud be able to load the content of a hidden element into your `.reserved-area` by referencing the id of the hidden element in the href of the corrosponding link:

```
$('.o-links').click(function() {

    // href has to be the id of the hidden content element
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.reserved-area')
        .hide('fast')
        .html($(href).html())
        .slideDown('slow');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Markus Kottländer. It works great.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to tell your script to load a default content with this: `$('.reserved-area').load($('.menu_top:first').attr('href'));` but it's not working. Can you help me with this please.

Comment: `$('.reserved-area').load($('.menu_top:first-child').attr('href'));` assuming that .menu-top is the class of the links not the class of the menu ul or any other wrapper.

Comment: I have a parent div with the class "menu_top" and inside of that parent div are the child links that will load the hidden files into the reserved_are div.

Comment: Then it has to be `$('.menu_top a:first-child')`.

Comment: I have this: `$('.reserved-area').load($('.menu_top a:first-child').attr('href'));` but it's not working.

Comment: Right above the one you gave me.